# Why can I not connect to my wireless network after I upgraded to 13.04?

Tags: wireless, networking, upgrade, 13.04

I just upgraded to 13.04 from 12.10 and discovered I was unable to connect to my home wireless network even though I can detect the network (and neighboring networks). 
However, I was able to connect via an ethernet cable to the router.

I noticed quite a few people were having similar issues and was wondering if anybody had reached a breakthrough. I tried disabling and re-enabling the wireless card, rebooting the computer, and rebooting the router all to no avail.

Some miscellaneous facts:

- I am running a Broadcom 4313 wireless card and my computer is a Dell N5010.
- My region is USA.
- When I upgraded to 12.10, I had to reinstall the driver set for bcmwl.

Answer (score 0):

Some problem with Broadcom 43142, after up-date from 12.10 to 13.04,

For Broadcom 4313 take a look to [this](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php) or [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2125464)